# Minimal number of generators ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $\mathfrak{a}=(x^n,\ldots,p^{n-1}x,p^n)$ ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
>   Show that the minimal number of generators of $\mathfrak{a}$ is $n+1$.

My strategy to prove this is to use one of the consequences of Nakayama Lemma; that is, to show that $\bar{x^n},\ldots,\bar{p^{n-1}x},\bar{p^n}$ is basis for the $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,p)\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module (vector space) $\mathfrak{a}/(x,p)\mathfrak{a}$. However, I was not able to show linear independence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sound approach!

Let $R=\Bbb Z[x]$ and
$\newcommand{\pp}{\mathfrak{p}}\pp=(x,p)$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=\pp^n$. So all one has to do is to prove that
$\pp^n/\pp^{n+1}$ has dimension $n+1$ over $R/\pp$. This is equivalent to
$|\pp^n/\pp^{n+1}|=p^{n+1}$, and that will follow by induction from
$|R/\pp^n|=p^{n(n-1)/2}$. But the $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$
form a system of coset representatives for $\pp^n$ in $R$
where $0\le a_j<p^{n-j}$.

Comment: As there is a commutative algebra tag, one can intepret the answer as follows. The ring $R_p$ is a regular local ring with maximal ideal $(x,p)$R_p. The associated graded ring is a polynomial ring in two variables (the images of $x$ and $p$) over $F_p$, and $p^n/p^{n+1}$ is the $n$-graded piece. Then the binomial formula shows the result.